# Make a Square Pseudo Element Only using Padding

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Why isn't a pseudo element with equal padding on all sides a square?

I am only able to achieve a square pseudo element when the right/left padding is 1.5 times that of the top/bottom padding.

See code below.

```css
button{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border:none;
  font-size:16px;
}

.icon::before {
    // position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    content: "";
    background: black; 
}

.icon2::before {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    content: "";
    background: black; 
}
```

```html
<p>Pseudo element: padding on all sides is 20px.</p>
<button class="icon">
  Click Me
</button> 

<p>Pseudo element: padding on top/bottom is 20px, padding on left/right is 30px.</p>
<button class="icon2">
  Click Me
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is treated as an inline element by default and the `font-size` will impact the size of the element. Change `font-size: 0;` or add `display: block;` with a matching height/width and it will be a square.

```css
button{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border:none;
  font-size:16px;
}

.icon::before {
    // position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    content: "";
    background: black; 
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.icon2::before {
    padding: 20px;
    content: "";
    background: black; 
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Pseudo element: padding on all sides is 20px.</p>
<button class="icon">
  Click Me
</button> 

<p>Pseudo element: padding on top/bottom is 20px, padding on left/right is 30px.</p>
<button class="icon2">
  Click Me
</button>
```

Comment: Changing `font-size` to `0px` solved my issue. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

See Michael's answer for an answer to the why in your question.

I would just like to point out, that most of the time the answer to your *title* is to use the fact that percentage padding is relative to the width of the thing. Yes, width, not height. I.e. you can add `padding-bottom: 100%` to achieve a square. Or make that 62.5% to achieve a 16:9 ratio e.g. for videos.

```css
.square {
  width: 100px;
}

.square::before {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Just watch out if you are changing the width of your pseudo-element to anything but 100%. If for example you set its width to 50%, you'd expect its padding-top/bottom to be a percentage of the pseudo-element's width. But it's not; it's a percentage of the real element's width.

Answer (score 0):

generated content inherits font-size and its line-height from parent.

You can reset font-size to hide both or only line-height.

```css
button{
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  border:none;
  font-size:16px;
}

.icon::before {
    font-size:0;/* remove space used from inserted text and line-height*/
    padding: 10%;/* 10% of 200px width is 20px */
    vertical-align:middle;/* can be usefull;*/
    margin-right:0.25rem;/* keep away from next phrasing content */
    content: "";
    background: black; 
}

.icon2::before {
    padding: 20px 30px;
    content: "";
    background: black; 
}
```

```html
<p>Pseudo element: padding on all sides is 20px.</p>
<button class="icon">
  Click Me
</button> 

<p>Pseudo element: padding on top/bottom is 20px, padding on left/right is 30px.</p>
<button class="icon2">
  Click Me
</button>
```